# What could cause (managed) UIAutomation to get a self reference when enumerating children

Tags: c#, .net, ui-automation

Have come across a dialog where a particular group of controls seems to be recursively referencing itself.  Of note the application provides an MSAA / LegacyAccessible interface to the UI Automation framework, such apps seem to be more fragile and seem to cause all sorts of grief, may or may not be relevant to this issue though.

So as an example, searching a window using FindFirst, if the element is before this self referencing element all is well, if it is after then this goes on forever pooling memory in both the client and server.

```
Condition condition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsPasswordProperty, true);
AutomationElement myPassword = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, condition);
```

Working through direct children has the same issue

```
private void WalkControlElements(AutomationElement rootElement, ...)
{
    AutomationElementCollection childElements = rootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Automation.ControlViewCondition);

    foreach (AutomationElement elementNode in childElements)
    {
        WalkControlElements(elementNode, ... );
    }
}
```

Working through TreeWalker.[ControlIViewWalker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.treewalker.controlviewwalker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has the same issue

```
private void WalkControlElements(AutomationElement rootElement, ...)
{
    AutomationElement elementNode = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker.GetFirstChild(rootElement);

    while (elementNode != null)
    {
        WalkControlElements(elementNode, ... );
        elementNode = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker.GetNextSibling(elementNode);
    }
}
```

It should look like

```
  group ""
     button "Home"
```

What it is looking like

```
  group ""
     button "Home"
     group ""
        button "Home"
        group ""
           button "Home"
           group ""
              button "Home"
              group ""
                 ...
```

An interesting thing though is that some other tools don't seem to be having this trouble.
Inpsect in either MSAA or UIAutomation mode doesn't grow an infinite tree.

So this leaves me wondering, what is it I'm doing wrong, or have not done that allows Inspect to work, but causes me an infinite recursion.
It appears from other SO comments that Inspect uses the native interface, and the issue might be with the Managed interface.

**If it cannot be fixed, can such a scenario be identified?**

Keeping a list of the controls during the recursive function, A simple check for having seen the element before didn't result in a match.

```
ref List<AutomationElement> controls
  if (controls.Contains(autoElement))
```

Comment: For "Oracle RightNow citaus" I found that while enumerating children I could check each child's parent value with the starting parent to find broken tree sections, and then break out of that part of the recursion early.  I'm not sure that this will be a good general solution.

Comment: Do you have access to the code for the application you are attempting to automate? When I first started writing automation peers many of the examples I ran into included the parent in the list of peers. I would check and see if the OnCreateAutomationPeer override is adding the parent as a child of itself.

Comment: Thanks @MaxYoung  unfortunately I don't have access to the source to check such.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, we need add more a valid method here to validate an element (says node in control chain in case we use TreeWalker to navigate control).
A valid method can based on the following way (one of or combination of them):

- Method GetUpdatedCache with input CacheRequest::Current: This method
  will try creat a clone of object if object is exist actually.
  Otherwise, an exception may be raised.
- Try to GetHashCode of element/object: In some specific case, an
  invalid element will have negative value/hash code.

In additional, it seems that UI Automation technology rely on specific platform (of Application) (not entirely), so we can determine which platform application belongs to (say win32, winform, wpf..) before we figure out solution to validate.

If we have a valid method strictly enough, we can do 2 things:

- Retrieve actual element to work on.
- Avoid of breaking down if API got problem when navigate to an invalid
  node itself.

Answer (score 0):

On experimental solution I've found to this specific application.

Some children have invalid parents

```
group ""
   button "Home"  <-- want this item, but item has invalid parent!
   group ""       <-- don't want item, item has invalid parent, and all children do also
      button "Home"
      group ""
```

Excluding anything with an 'invalid' parent

```
private void WalkControlElements(AutomationElement rootElement, ...)
{
    AutomationElementCollection childElements = rootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Automation.ControlViewCondition);

    foreach (AutomationElement elementNode in childElements)
    {
        if( rootElement == TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker.GetParent(elementNode) )
            WalkControlElements(elementNode, ... );
    }
}
```

results in looking like

```
group ""
```

Not all of those children should be ignored :|  missing the button "home"

Finding a compromise, evaluating invalid structure in a slightly lazy way.

```
private void WalkControlElements(AutomationElement rootElement, ...){
     WalkControlElements(elementNode, false, ... );
}

private void WalkControlElements(AutomationElement rootElement, bool treeValidationExceptionShouldFail, ...)
{
    AutomationElementCollection childElements = rootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Automation.ControlViewCondition);

    foreach (AutomationElement elementNode in childElements)
    {
        if( rootElement == TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker.GetParent(elementNode) )
            WalkControlElements(elementNode, treeValidationExceptionShouldFail, ... );
        else
            WalkControlElements(elementNode, true, ... );
    }
}
```

results in looking like

```
group ""
   button "Home" 
   group ""       <-- don't want, but at least we stopped recursion
```